# Solve the SDE $dX_t=dB_t+\frac{c-X_t}{T-t}dt$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

How to solve the following SDE characterizing Brownian motion with fixed end point $c$ at time $T$?

$$\mathrm dX_t=\mathrm dB_t+\frac{c-X_t}{T-t}\,\mathrm dt$$

I do not believe a strong solution exists, by ito lemma it would seem contradictory. Although, intuitively the solution should be something like

$$X_t=B_t+\frac{t(c-B_T)}{T}$$

Tips for solving the equation are welcome!

Comment: This is a Brownian bridge you can check Protter's book where there is a chapter dedicated "augmented" filtration which is the underlying subject but this a very studied matter so there is plenty of literature on this on hte web for example here : http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Bridge.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SDE is a special case for Hull-White SDE, which can be solved
analytically. Recall that $X$ is a Hull-White process if $X$ satisfies
a SDE of the form: 
$$
dX_{t}=\beta_{t}(\alpha_{t}-X_{t})dt+\sigma_{t}dB_{t},
$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\sigma$ are deterministic processes (and are
usually identified as functions with domain $[0,\infty)$ and codomain
$\mathbb{R}$). For your case, $\alpha_{t}=c$, $\beta_{t}=\frac{1}{T-t}$,
$\sigma_{t}=1$.

The trick to solve such SDE is to consider a suitable integrating
factor $\mu$ (a deterministic process)

Apply Ito's lemma, then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & d(X_{t}\mu_{t})\\
 & = & \mu_{t}'X_{t}dt+\mu_{t}dX_{t}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Choose $\mu_{t}$ such that $\mu_{t}'X_{t}+\mu_{t}\beta_{t}(-X_{t})=0$.
That is, $\mu_{t}'=\beta_{t}\mu_{t}$. Note that, there is more than
one choice for $\mu$ but any choice is OK. Then we observe that 
$$
d(\mu_{t}X_{t})=\gamma_{1}(t)dt+\gamma_{2}(t)dB_{t}
$$
for some deterministic functions $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$.
The above SDE can be integrated directly.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer. Just a quick question, how do I deal with the discontinuity at $T$, since $\mu_t=\frac{1}{T-t}$? Is it OK to still have the same solution? Further, is $\int_0^t \frac{(T-t)}{T-s}dB_s$ in law the same as $B(t)-\frac{t}{T}B(T)$ then?

Comment: The SDE may only have solution for $t\in[0,T)$ (but I have not examined that issue in details).

Comment: $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{T-t}{T-s}dB_{s}=(T-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dB_{s}}{T-s}$.
Now, it is well-known that if the integrand $f$ is deterministic
( and square-integrable), $\int_{0}^{t}f(s)dB_{s}$ is normally distributed
with zero mean and variance $\int_{0}^{t}f^{2}(s)ds$. For our case,
let $t\in[0,T)$ be fixed. then $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(T-s)^{2}}ds=\frac{1}{T-t}-\frac{1}{T}$.
Hence, $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{T-t}{T-s}dB_{s}$ is normally distributed
with zero mean and variance $(T-t)^{2}\{\frac{1}{T-t}-\frac{1}{T}\}.$

Comment: $B_{t}-\frac{t}{T}B_{T}=B_{t}(1-\frac{t}{T})-\frac{t}{T}(B_{T}-B_{t})$.
Note that $B_{t}$, $B_{T}-B_{t}$ are independent, normally distributed
with zero mean and variance $t$ and $T-t$ respectively, so $B_{t}(1-\frac{t}{T})-\frac{t}{T}(B_{T}-B_{t})$
is normally distributed with zero mean and variance $(1-\frac{t}{T})^{2}t+(\frac{t}{T})^{2}(T-t)$.